# My scale bar in transform is in orange color

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, blend-files

[image]

My scale transform is in orange color bar.If i apply the scale and save the project also,when i reopen it the scale is not applied and the orange color continues in the scale bar.I couldnt figure it out what mistake i have done here.So please help me to come out from this issue.

Answer (score 3):

you have set a keyframe to scale. This happens e.g. if you press 'I' when the cursor is above the scale.

If you want to delete the keyframe(s), select your object which has the keyframes,  hover the cursor over the keyframe panel and tap 'X' and then delete all keyframes.